# How to use Rest And Soap API in Magento After sales order to send information to courier partner

Tags: magento-1.7, soap, rest-api, soap-api-v2

I need to send. some information after sales ..to the courier company...
I need to build API in magento..when customer purchase anything...and place successful order. Then I want to send some information to our partner courier company. Like product name, customer address, customer name And some information...
Basically, I want to use rest and soap..for this. But I don't know which is good for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use magento event like "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" which will be called after successfull order.where you can write a method to call courier api using soap.You can get all the information from event object.

Sample

1)Place in config.xml

```
<events>
 <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <my_custom_module>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>my_custom_module_observer</class>
                        <method>sendtocourier</method>
                    </my_custom_module>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>           
        </events>
```

2) In class my_custom_module_observer, write method

```
function sendtocourier($observer){

$orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
        $orderId = current($orderIds);
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
//get all info from order

//call courier with soap
$client = new SoapClient('courire wsdl url', array('trace' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

}
```

Hope that helps